# Looping a query on Realm for android

Tags: android, for-loop, realm

How to loop a query on realm database?

I need to get all item defined by my array List of id..
only way i think is to implement a loop of my query.. but i cannot make it work.. here is my sample code..

```
for(Basket w : rResult){
        somethingList = realm.where(SomeThing.class).equalTo("something_id", w.getId()).findAll();
    }
```

i also tried doing a chain query describe in the documentation..

```
    for(Basket w : rResult){
        somethingList = somethingList.where().equalTo("something_id", w.getId()).findAll();
    }
```

can somebody show me how its done? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so i was up all night thinking for an answer.. the simple answer is just to loop the query before executing .findAll() action..

```
RealmResult<Something> somethingResult = realm.getInstance(context).where(Something.class).findAll();
RealmQuery<Basket> basketQuery = realm.where(Basket.class);

for(int i=0; i<somethingResult.size(); i++){
    if(i==0)
         basketQuery.equalTo("something_id", somethingResult.get(i).getId());
    else
         basketQuery.or().equalTo("something_id", somethingResult.get(i).getId());
}

basketList = basketQuery.findAll();
```

hope this will help others..